# Выдвижное меню на мобильной версии лагает:(

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Подскажите как устранить глюк у выдвижного меню?
Как только загрузился сайт и ты первый раз тапаешь по иконке, она как-то прерывисто раздвигает пункты меню. Потом нормально - плавненько, анимированенько. Делаем ребур страницы - и опять пырвый тап по иконке коротит меню. Т.е. именно при первом и повторных запусках сайта такая проблема. А когда несколько раз понажимаешь, она работает как надо.
Вот [линк](https://worldwarmworm.github.io/webdev/) на проект, поробуйте.

Я уже битый день репу чешу, сдался, решил написать)
Тестил на разных устройствах и браузерах.

Answer (score 0):

Поменяй вот это:

```
$('nav').slideToggle(500);
```

и вот это :

```
$('ul.menu').css({
  display: 'flex',
  'flex-direction': 'column'
});
```

местами

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: и у тебя ещё неправильно все это работает при определенных условиях.

Comment: например, если открыть меню и вернуться в фуллскрин

Comment: местами менял, все равно при первом выкате после загрузки троит(

Comment: я завел твой сайт у себя на пк, поменял местами то, что указал, все отлично работает

Comment: хм. а до того как поменял, подглючивало меню?

Comment: да, подглючивало

Comment: Ты полсекунды открываешь меню, потом резко переворачиваешь его, соответственно высота списка значительно меняется и происходит такой вот скачок. Когда ты поменял эти строки кода местами, твой список уже находится в вертикальном положении и потом ты просто полсекунды меняешь его высоту

Comment: Очень тебе признателен! Столько времени потратил на мой вопрос. Здоровья тебе и редбула)

Comment: А по поводу фулскрина у тебя просто пропадают пункты меню или в чем бага?

Comment: https://worldwarmworm.github.io/test/ это новый линк, создал другой репозиторий. тут пофикшено